# Why would an MSMQ msg be dispatched again after processing?

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

using Transactional MSMQ and WCF here in C#

sometimes for some reason, the message gets redispatched from the MSMQ even though the previous time, the message was processed successfully (i.e no unhandled exceptions or anything). There is only just the 1 msg I am placing on the queue.

any ideas why?

Sure, I am also debugging when the msg gets dispatched but I only have a very small number of breakpoints in certain areas and spend no longer than 3 seconds looking at the things I need to look at in that context of the msg being flowed into the system.

any ideas why duplicate dispatches?

Update: Code:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CustomMessage))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MessageA))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MessageB))]
public interface IMessageHandlerService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
        void ProcessMessage(MsmqMessage<CustomMessage> message);
    }

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false)]
    public sealed class MessageHandlerService : IMessageHandlerService
    {
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
        public void ProcessMessage(MsmqMessage<CustomMessage> message)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

my ABC:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="IncludeExceptionDetails">
          <callbackDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />          
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Services.Implementation.MessageHandler.MessageHandlerService">
        <endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\msgs" binding="msmqIntegrationBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageHandlerBinding" contract="Services.Contracts.Messages.IMessageHandlerService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <msmqIntegrationBinding>
        <binding name="MessageHandlerBinding" 
                 closeTimeout="00:30:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="01:00:00" 
                 retryCycleDelay="00:00:10" 
                 receiveRetryCount="0" 
                 exactlyOnce="true" 
                 maxRetryCycles="1" 
                 receiveErrorHandling="Move">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </msmqIntegrationBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I really don't understand how the question is vague and ambiguous :-)
Its simple. When wcf is bound to the msmq, sometimes the same message is dispatched twice even though the first message was successfully processed.

What other details do you need? Please tell!

Comment: bug in your (not shown) code?

Comment: It's almost certain that somehow, you're leaking the transaction, it's eventually rolling back (so the message goes back on the queue) and then you attempt to process it again. But you've not shown us any code, so I'm guessing it's a problem at line 37.

Comment: my apologies for not showing the code! please check my original post for the code